# How to add checkbox in Asp.net Gridview in all header columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am new in asp.net developer.

Populated a asp.net grid view with the help of data table and my all columns are dynamic.
Now i want to add a check box in my all columns dynamically bot do not want to add in rows.
One time i can check only one check box.If i am selecting second time check box in that case first selected check box should be unchecked.

My code is below:

```
protected void dgvWoList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[i] != null && (!e.Row.Cells[i].IsNullOrEmpty()))
                {
                    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
                    chk.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(chk);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now i am trying to uncheck the check box but unable to do. Plz help me.

Answers: 
Thanks a lot for your responses. Spl thanks AnthonyBCodes for your advise instead of check box use radio button which solved my problem. I changed my code from check box to radio button as below.

```
                        RadioButton chk = new RadioButton();
                        chk.GroupName = "radio";
                        chk.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(chk);
```

Comment: For one thing, it's called "ASP.NET" - no spaces. For another, you'll get a much better answer if you include the smallest amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [ask].

Comment: Please post some of your code.  Just reading your issue, you may want to use a Radio button as opposed to a checkbox.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. my code is below: I have my code in RowdataBound event.

Comment: I have updated my question with my code.

Comment: The code seems change non selected checkboxes, doesn't it?

Comment: The above code adding check box in header. Now i want to check only one check box. I do not want to check multiple check box from grid view header column.

Comment: At last, you should move above code to 'RowCreated' event.
Because `RowDataBound` doesn't fire if server validate fail.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the comments and edited into the question by the OP. Move to community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Thanks a lot for your responses. Special thanks @AnthonyBCodes for your advice instead of a check box use a radio button which solved my problem. I changed my code from a check box to a radio button as below.

```
                RadioButton chk = new RadioButton();
                chk.GroupName = "radio";
                chk.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(chk);
```